# Split Postgres query into readable snipptes

Tags: postgresql

I have a relative, not complex but long query string like:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(exp)))
    FROM (
      SELECT label as name, (
    SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(opt)))
        FROM (
            SELECT value as name, count as size FROM countoptions 
      ) opt
    ) as children
    FROM countoptions GROUP BY label 
    ) exp;
```

Later this query will become more complex, so I am looking for a technique to split the query in more readable parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were [Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) what you were looking for?

> WITH provides a way to write auxiliary statements for use in a larger
>   query. These statements, which are often referred to as Common Table
>   Expressions or CTEs, can be thought of as defining temporary tables
>   that exist just for one query. Each auxiliary statement in a WITH
>   clause can be a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE; and the WITH clause
>   itself is attached to a primary statement that can also be a SELECT,
>   INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE

Comment: Just not forget that CTE costs temp space if you query large data sets.
They are good for readability but not well optimized internally.